# Why does this get "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error?

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

Why do I get a `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` because of `objects[i]=rs.getObject(i+1);`? There are about 10,000 records with about 4,000 characters per record.

```
        String[] tableColumnsName = {idString, dateEnteredString, entryString, operatorString, licenseNoString, lastModifiedString};
        DefaultTableModel aModel = (DefaultTableModel) logEntryTable.getModel();
        aModel.setColumnIdentifiers(tableColumnsName);

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
        try {
            rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            int colNo = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            while(rs.next()){
                Object[] objects = new Object[colNo];
                for(int i=0;i<colNo;i++){
                    objects[i]=rs.getObject(i+1);
                }
                aModel.addRow(objects);
            }
            logEntryTable.setModel(aModel);

            logEntryTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(30);

            rs.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            showCantConnectErrorDialog();
        }
```

Comment: How big are the data in the columns?  What is the maximum size of any record?  1100 records sounds suspiciously low to trigger an OOME.

Comment: There is a field that's a text field which has no max chars in the mysql db, but it contains about two paragraphs of text in each.

Comment: Two paragraphs is still not very precise. But 1000 characters per paragraph?

Comment: 3792 characters per entry and 10,000 entries. Sorry I was way off before.

Comment: 40,000,000 of characters, about 80MBs of Java heap + all the other stuff and memory needed for temporary sotrage... 128MBs may not be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JVM has run out of memory. Potentially when JVM is short on memory OutOfMemoryError may appear in any place in the code that allocates memory. Try increasing your heap size using [-Xmx parameter](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/docs/JmolUserGuide/ch02s07.html).

Comment: I increased to 128 MB in Debug mode of eclipse, but I couldn't set it using the command line. Is there a way to set it at run-time? I would need to make sure each user's Java VM had enough memory allocated to the heap.

Comment: How do you run your code at "runtime"? -Xmx is a parameter to JVM, you need to pass to java process you run your code with in command-line.

Comment: Ahh, that's right. Is there a way to pass in the parameter upon execution of an executable jar file? Basically, I have a Java desktop application that is a log for workers out in the field and the application will go on customer's computers and I need to make sure each customer has enough memory allocated in the heap for their Java VM so they can view the large amount of log entries as time goes on.

Comment: Of course, just add -Xmx1024M (or any other number thta is big enough) to the command-line e.g. java -Xmx1024M -jar my.jar.

Comment: You can create a bat/sh file that will contain that command line with proper memory settings.

Comment: I found that launch4j is exactly what I'm looking for. I can generate an exe (which works b/c our users are only Windows users) and launch4j allows me to set JVM params.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with ^^ you need to increase your heap size, or if that's not possible, reduce everything to get it as space efficient as possible.